# TeamCity Use Credentials of User Currently Logged In

Tags: powershell, teamcity

Here is my problem. I have a build step in TeamCity that fires a powershell which updates a configuration parameter in another TC sub-project and resets the build counter via an API call. To do so, I have to pass valid credentials, which I am setting up as a parameter to be entered when the a custom build is run. This works great, however, for some reason if the password is typo'd even once(and I am using TC's password type parameter so it is masked, making this easy to do), the user's windows account is locked immediately. I assume this is something TC is doing to send the request multiple times, but regardless of why it is happening and is obviously not ideal.

The most ideal solution would simply be able to run the build using the credentials of the user who is kicking it off. So far as I can tell, there is no 'Run As' option, so is there a way for me to retrieve and use the password of the current user logged in to TeamCity, perhaps as a system variable? I've read through the documentation and have not had any luck finding what I need. Maybe there is a way to do this through powershell?

Any ideas/suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

JetBrains is working on https://github.com/JetBrains/teamcity-runas-plugin
I hope it will appear soon